# Positioning buttons in responsive web design

Tags: html, css, button, responsive

I'm currently having issues with the positioning of buttons on a website when the page size changes.

I have included a number of different screenshots to show the different positions of the buttons.

When I change the size of the window, the buy button will move out of place in the panel and this obviously destroys the look of the website. I have tried changing the positioning to percentages however this still has not solved the problem.

[Standard window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWvWa.png)
 [Half window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTLLH.jpg)

Code shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cookers</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name ="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Styling of navbar, jumbotron and footer -->
    <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default rounded borders and increase the bottom margin */ 
        .navbar {
          margin-bottom: 0px;
          border-radius: 0;
          padding-bottom: 0;
        }

        /* Remove the jumbotron's default bottom margin */ 
         .jumbotron {
          margin-bottom: 0;
          background-color: #ffcccc
        }

        /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
        footer {
          background-color: #f2f2f2;
          padding: 25px;
        }

        .content {
            position: relative;
        }

        #buttonRight {
            position: absolute;
            /*transition: .5s ease;*/
            top:85%;
            /*bottom: 5%;*/
            right:10%;
            /*bottom:15%;
            left:85%;*/
        }

        .sidebar-nav {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            width:275px;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            list-style: none;
        }

        .header-wrapper {
            position: fixed;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Large heading at top of webpage-->
    <div id = "header-wrapper">
    <<div class = "jumbotron">
        <div class = "container text-center">
            <h1>Stephens Catering Back Catalog</h1>
            <h2>A template for the listing of backlogged stock</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--The navigation bar at the top of each page -->
    <nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class = "container-fluid">
            <div class = "navbar-header">
                <button type = "button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class = "navbar-brand" href="Home.html">Stephens Catering</a>
            </div>

            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="OurProducts.html">Our Products
                        <span class = "caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="Cookers.html">Cookers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Fridges.html">Fridges</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Misc.html">Misc</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
        <!-- Button to toggle sidebar menu -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-lg-12">
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle" align="right">Toggle Menu</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--The sidebar for the products pages -->
    <div id = "wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id = "sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class = "sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">Categories</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Cookers.html">Cookers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Fridges.html">Fridges</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Misc.html">Misc</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Sidebar Wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->

    <!-- The items which are on sale -->
    <!-- Top left -->
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-sm-4">
                <div class = "panel panel-primary">
                    <div class = "panel-heading"> Cooker 1</div>
                    <div class = "panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" style = "width:100%" alt = "Image"></div>
                    <div class = "panel-footer">Was £500<br> <strong>NOW £100</strong> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="buttonRight">BUY</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <!-- Top Middle -->
            <div class = "col-sm-4">
                <div class = "panel panel-danger">
                        <div class = "panel-heading"> Cooker 2</div>
                        <div class = "panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" style = "width:100%" alt = "Image"></div>
                        <div class = "panel-footer">Was £200<br> <strong>NOW £50</strong><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id = "buttonRight">BUY</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <!-- Top Right -->
            <div class = "col-sm-4">
                <div class = "panel panel-success">
                        <div class = "panel-heading"> Cooker 3</div>
                        <div class = "panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" style = "width:100%" alt = "Image"></div>
                        <div class = "panel-footer">Was £200<br> <strong>NOW £50</strong><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id = "buttonRight">BUY</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <!--/TopRow -->

    <!-- Bottom Left -->
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-sm-4">
                <div class = "panel panel-primary">
                    <div class = "panel-heading"> Cooker 1</div>
                    <div class = "panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" style = "width:100%" alt = "Image"></div>
                    <div class = "panel-footer">Was £500<br> <strong>NOW £100</strong><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-right" id = "buttonRight">BUY</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <!-- Bottom Middle -->
            <div class = "col-sm-4">
                <div class = "panel panel-danger">
                        <div class = "panel-heading"> Cooker 2</div>
                        <div class = "panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" style = "width:100%" alt = "Image"></div>
                        <div class = "panel-footer">Was £200<br> <strong>NOW £50</strong><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-right" id = "buttonRight">BUY</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <!-- Bottom Right -->
            <div class = "col-sm-4">
                <div class = "panel panel-success">
                        <div class = "panel-heading"> Cooker 3</div>
                        <div class = "panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" style = "width:100%" alt = "Image"></div>
                        <div class = "panel-footer">Was £200<br> <strong>NOW £50</strong><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-right" id = "buttonRight">BUY</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/BottomRow -->

    <!--Page Wrapper -->
    </div>

    <!--JQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!--Bootstrap Core Javascript -->
    <script src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });
    </script>

    <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
      <p>Online Store Copyright</p>
          <form class="form-inline">Get deals:
            <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Up</button>
          </form>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a working demo in JSfiddle? so we can test and resolve the problem.

Comment: Im new to the website so im unsure how to do this, I will give it a go though. Thanks!

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: have you tried setting up whitespaces like this?                                   `.btn-responsive {
    white-space: normal !important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}`  Also add `btn-responsive` class to the button tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are making the `button` element `position absolute`, make its parent `div` `positioned relative`.

```
.panel-footer{
position:relative;
}

#buttonRight{
   position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    margin: auto;
    right: 2%;
}
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/bfp0z1r5/11/)

Comment: That was an incredibly simple fix! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Modification in Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name ="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Styling of navbar, jumbotron and footer -->
        <style>
        /* Remove the navbar's default rounded borders and increase the bottom margin */ 
            .navbar {
              margin-bottom: 0px;
              border-radius: 0;
              padding-bottom: 0;
            }

            /* Remove the jumbotron's default bottom margin */ 
             .jumbotron {
              margin-bottom: 0;
              background-color: #ffcccc
            }

            /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
            footer {
              background-color: #f2f2f2;
              padding: 25px;
            }

            .content {
                position: relative;
            }



            .sidebar-nav {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                width:275px;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                list-style: none;
            }

            .header-wrapper {
                position: fixed;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                width:100%;
            }
            #buttonRight{float:right;}
            .panel-footer {
        padding: 10px 15px 25px!important;}

        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <!-- Large heading at top of webpage-->
        <div id = "header-wrapper">
        <<div class = "jumbotron">
            <div class = "container text-center">
                <h1>Stephens Catering Back Catalog</h1>
                <h2>A template for the listing of backlogged stock</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--The navigation bar at the top of each page -->
        <nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class = "container-fluid">
                <div class = "navbar-header">
                    <button type = "button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class = "navbar-brand" href="Home.html">Stephens Catering</a>
                </div>

                <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="OurProducts.html">Our Products
                            <span class = "caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="Cookers.html">Cookers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Fridges.html">Fridges</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Misc.html">Misc</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
            <!-- Button to toggle sidebar menu -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle" align="right">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--The sidebar for the products pages -->
        <div id = "wrapper">
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div id = "sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    <li class = "sidebar-brand">
                        <a href="#">Categories</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Cookers.html">Cookers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Fridges.html">Fridges</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Misc.html">Misc</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Sidebar Wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->

        <!-- The items which are on sale -->
        <!-- Top left -->
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                    <div class = "panel panel-primary">
                        <div class = "panel-heading"> Cooker 1</div>
                        <div class = "panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" style = "width:100%" alt = "Image"></div>
                        <div class = "panel-footer">Was £500<br> <strong>NOW £100</strong> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="buttonRight">BUY</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <!-- Top Middle -->
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                    <div class = "panel panel-danger">
                            <div class = "panel-heading"> Cooker 2</div>
                            <div class = "panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" style = "width:100%" alt = "Image"></div>
                            <div class = "panel-footer">Was £200<br> <strong>NOW £50</strong><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id = "buttonRight">BUY</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <!-- Top Right -->
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                    <div class = "panel panel-success">
                            <div class = "panel-heading"> Cooker 3</div>
                            <div class = "panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" style = "width:100%" alt = "Image"></div>
                            <div class = "panel-footer">Was £200<br> <strong>NOW £50</strong><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id = "buttonRight">BUY</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><br>
        <!--/TopRow -->

        <!-- Bottom Left -->
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                    <div class = "panel panel-primary">
                        <div class = "panel-heading"> Cooker 1</div>
                        <div class = "panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" style = "width:100%" alt = "Image"></div>
                        <div class = "panel-footer">Was £500<br> <strong>NOW £100</strong><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id = "buttonRight">BUY</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <!-- Bottom Middle -->
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                    <div class = "panel panel-danger">
                            <div class = "panel-heading"> Cooker 2</div>
                            <div class = "panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" style = "width:100%" alt = "Image"></div>
                            <div class = "panel-footer">Was £200<br> <strong>NOW £50</strong><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id = "buttonRight">BUY</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <!-- Bottom Right -->
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                    <div class = "panel panel-success">
                            <div class = "panel-heading"> Cooker 3</div>
                            <div class = "panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" style = "width:100%" alt = "Image"></div>
                            <div class = "panel-footer">Was £200<br> <strong>NOW £50</strong><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id = "buttonRight">BUY</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/BottomRow -->

        <!--Page Wrapper -->
        </div>

        <!--JQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <!--Bootstrap Core Javascript -->
        <script src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!--Menu Toggle Script -->
        <script>
            $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
            });
        </script>

        <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
          <p>Online Store Copyright</p>
              <form class="form-inline">Get deals:
                <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Up</button>
              </form>
        </footer>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You should make `.panel-footer {position: relative;}`

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


/* Remove the jumbotron's default bottom margin */

.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ffcccc
}


/* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */

footer {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 25px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}

.panel-footer {
  position: relative;
}

#buttonRight {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 22%;
  right: 3%;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 275px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.header-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="header-wrapper">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>Stephens Catering Back Catalog</h1>
      <h2>A template for the listing of backlogged stock</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<!--The navigation bar at the top of each page -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.html">Stephens Catering</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="OurProducts.html">Our Products
                        <span class = "caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="Cookers.html">Cookers</a></li>
            <li><a href="Fridges.html">Fridges</a></li>
            <li><a href="Misc.html">Misc</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
<!-- Button to toggle sidebar menu -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle" align="right">Toggle Menu</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--The sidebar for the products pages -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">Categories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="Cookers.html">Cookers</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="Fridges.html">Fridges</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="Misc.html">Misc</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Sidebar Wrapper -->

  <!-- Page Content -->

  <!-- The items which are on sale -->
  <!-- Top left -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading"> Cooker 1</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Was £500
            <br> <strong>NOW £100</strong>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="buttonRight">BUY</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Top Middle -->
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-danger">
          <div class="panel-heading"> Cooker 2</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Was £200
            <br> <strong>NOW £50</strong>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="buttonRight">BUY</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Top Right -->
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading"> Cooker 3</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Was £200
            <br> <strong>NOW £50</strong>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="buttonRight">BUY</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!--/TopRow -->

  <!-- Bottom Left -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading"> Cooker 1</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Was £500
            <br> <strong>NOW £100</strong>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-right" id="buttonRight">BUY</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Bottom Middle -->
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-danger">
          <div class="panel-heading"> Cooker 2</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Was £200
            <br> <strong>NOW £50</strong>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-right" id="buttonRight">BUY</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Bottom Right -->
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading"> Cooker 3</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/Cooker1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Was £200
            <br> <strong>NOW £50</strong>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-right" id="buttonRight">BUY</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/BottomRow -->

  <!--Page Wrapper -->
</div>

<!--JQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!--Bootstrap Core Javascript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--Menu Toggle Script -->
<script>
  $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  });

</script>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Online Store Copyright</p>
  <form class="form-inline">Get deals:
    <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the effort, the first answer got it though!